# how to show record in many to many relationships mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables.

The first table called users

```
id username email
1  lahuudat lada@gmail.com
2  dvtruong vitr@gmail.com
3  phuocng  phcng@gmail.com
```

The second table called users_groups

```
id user_id group_id
1  1       1
2  1       2
3  2       2
4  3       2
```

The third table called groups

```
id name
1  admin
2  manager
```

I want to get results that are managed but not admin.

```
username email            role
dvtruong vitr@gmail.com   manager
phuocng  phcng@gmail.com  manager
```

I have tried some code

```
select users.username, users.email, groups.name FROM users INNER JOIN users_groups ON users.id = users_groups.user_id INNER JOIN groups ON users_groups.group_id = groups.id WHERE groups.id = 2 and groups.id != 1
```

But it does not show the correct results.
My english is very bad, i tried, using google translate. Hope everyone can understand. Thanks everyone

Comment: I just want to get results that are managed but not admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `NOT IN` in the where clause such as :

```
select users.username,
       users.email,
       groups.name
FROM users
INNER JOIN users_groups
ON users.id = users_groups.user_id
INNER JOIN groups
ON users_groups.group_id = groups.id
WHERE groups.id = 2
AND users.id NOT IN
(
    SELECT ug.user_id
    FROM users_groups ug
    WHERE ug.group_id <> 2
);
```

**Output**

```
| username | email           | name    |
| -------- | --------------- | ------- |
| dvtruong | vitr@gmail.com  | manager |
| phuocng  | phcng@gmail.com | manager |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n3v5gn9au4Jc61PTGDv8g7/0)

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
select u.username, u.email, g.name 
FROM users u, groups g
where g.id=2 and u.id NOT IN(select user_id from users_groups where group_id <> 2)
```